# call an external program from the tab tkinter notebook

Tags: python, tkinter, jupyter-notebook

I created a widget with python tkinter notebook. I have to manage a tab on an external program, in this case a table maintenance proscram in MySQL. com do you recall the external program and manage it in the tab.

Comment: Its hard to understand what you are asking ... but i think you want `os.system(command)` or `subprocess.Popen`

Comment: Good morning, you're right I could not explain, I'll try now. Basically I'm using the notebook widget with tkinter. In practice I would like to open an external program from a tab. In practice if I have tab1, tab2, tab3, etc., I would like to encapsulate in tab2 an external program written with tkinter. Thanks if you need more details let me know. Thank you

Comment: Good morning, you're right I could not explain, I'll try now. Basically I'm using the notebook widget with tkinter. In practice I would like to open an external program from a tab. In practice if I have tab1, tab2, tab3, etc., I would like to encapsulate in tab2 an external program written with tkinter. Thanks if you need more details let me know. Thank you